# Fabric.js svg with multiple paths cliping to multiple images

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

When one svg file has multiple paths(lets say objects) I need to clip those paths to multiple images. I should maintain actual positions of the paths. When adding an image can I clip this image to selected path?

Currently I can only clip svg to one image. But Thats not what I want.

https://jsfiddle.net/hydride/wh35ymev/

```
var svgEl = document.body.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(svgEl);

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.backgroundColor = 'rgb(150,150,150)';
var obj;
var path = fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgStr,function(objects, options) {
  obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  obj.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
  obj.setFill('transparent');
  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});

$("#addButton").click(function(){
    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function (img) {
    img.scaleToHeight(canvas.height).set({
      clipTo: function (ctx) {
        obj.render(ctx);
      }
    });
    canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
});
```